Are mathematical proofs basically graphs?
Coming from an algorithmic/programming point of view, are mathematical proofs basically directed graph traversals, or more precisely, finite state machines?
Typical structure of mathematical statements:
LHS (relation) RHS

e.g., $\vec x \cdot \vec y \leq |\vec x| |\vec y|$
Proposed structure of the proof graph:
root_node: definitions and declarations of operands and operators
edges: axioms/postulates/theorems
nodes: change in state of operands and relation ( =, ≤, ≥, <, > ) with the previous value

Traverse this graph starting from LHS till you reach RHS and obtain the same relation operator.
If this graph is true, can we go forward in restructuring it (in order to assign weights to edges) to find an proof in least number of arguments, i.e., implement something like Dijkstra's algorithm?

Brief Googling yielded this: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S157106610580204X

Also this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/249383/is-there-a-database-for-tracking-the-dependencies-of-mathematical-theorems
